# Can a DJI Matrice 100/200/210 be controlled solely using a 3G/4G link without a remote controller?

Tags: dji-sdk

Is it possible to autonomously command a DJI Matrice, using an NVIDIA TX2 hooked up to a 3G/4G USB modem, to fly without an intervening remote controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Theoretically yes.

You will need to:

1/ Add an Onboard computer. My suggestion is a Nvidia TX2 with an orbitty carrier board.

2/ Build an OnboardSDK app with the aircraft controls you want.

3/ Build a communication protocol through 3G/4G and a client/server architecture to send the commands you want to your onboard app.

Answer (score 0):

M100 i have dont support flying without a remote controller.

M100 is only used on turned-on remote controller.

if the remote controller is not powered, M100 is blinking yellow light, then go to failsafe mode.

These drones have a each controller and make a pair set with a remote controller.